# OpenVPN nameservers ignored by NetworkManager or whatever

Tags: dns, openvpn

I'm using Elementary OS. I've followed a dozen suggestions from different websites and nothing helps.

I use OpenVPN client to connect to an office network. The company I work for has provided me the `.ovpn` and other files necessary for configuring OpenVPN client.

Per OpenVPN log files, I am able to connect to the VPN just fine. Indeed, I can ping IP addresses from the office network. I can also see the VPN's nameserver address is being pushed from the server: `Mon Apr 20 23:46:07 2015 us=296304 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,topology subnet,dhcp-option DNS {{nameserver IP is shown here}},route-gateway <REDACTED>,route <REDACTED> <REDACTED>,...`.

However no office hosts resolve.

If I run `nslookup {{hostname}}`, it says "server can't find {{hostname}}: NXDOMAIN". If I run `nslookup {{hostname}} {{VPN nameserver address}}`, it resolves the name just fine.

So, why isn't NetworkManager or whatever handles DNS queries on my system using the VPN nameserver, and how do I get it to work?

Output of `nslookup askubuntu.com`:

```
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 104.16.18.44
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 104.16.16.44
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 104.16.15.44
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 104.16.19.44
Name:   askubuntu.com
Address: 104.16.17.44
```

Comment: I'm presuming this is a TAP setup, not TUN?

Comment: Do you have the `update-resolv-conf` script at `/etc/openvpn/` ?

Comment: which profile do launch the openvpn client ? it may be a missing right. If openvpn client is launched by root you should have the right resolver.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is choosing this openvpn easy-setup by using the following command:

```
wget git.io/vpn ; chmod 777 vpn ; ./vpn
```

This script auto-detects the IP address of the machine it is run on, lets you choose the DNS, protocol, and port.  The rest is done for you. *I recommend this because you can choose the DNS: "System default resolvers"* This lets you use the nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf. To change these, just do:

```
nano resolv.conf
```

and change `nameserver $IP` to `nameserver (Your DNS)`.

Keep in mind that the nameservers reset at boot, but I *do* have a solution for this. The easiest way that I know of is using:

```
nano /etc/bashrc
```

and adding the following line anywhere in the file:

```
echo (Insert your nameserver) >> /etc/resolv.conf
```